# EntityFramework lazy load from external source

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a SQL 2008 R2 database, which I access using Entity Framework. One table has a property which has to be populated from an external source. The fetched value should then be cached in the table.

How can I inject code into the entity context, that will allow me to fetch this data only when needed, and a cached value does not exist?

Comment: Really, your only choice is to poll the database periodically to see if the value has changed.  If you post more details I could make a few suggestions about the most efficient way to do that.  e.g. How is the data cached - is a new record created, or is a property on an existing record updated?  etc..

Comment: What is the question? What is a table in your question? Is the value cached in the application or in the database. Table is database consturct, class or entity is application construct.

Comment: @HiredMind The data is cached in a new record referenced by a foregin key